# How do I retrieve table data when it is a 'level down' in the class definition?

Tags: vb.net, linq, entity-framework

VS2013, VB, EF, LINQ

While maybe I could have a better model design, this is what I have:

```
Partial Public Class ApplicationDbContext
  Public Property ChannelItems As DbSet(Of ChannelItem)
  Public Property UserPosts As DbSet(Of UserPost)
End Class

Public Class ChannelItem
  Public Property ChannelItemID As Integer
  Public Property Anchor As New UserPost
  Public Property Comments As New List(Of UserPost)
  Public Property SpecialPermissionReq As Boolean
End Class

Public Class UserPost
  Public Property UserPostID As Integer
  ...
  Public Property HasBeenReadBy As New List(Of HasBeenReadBy)
End Class

Public Class HasBeenReadBy 
  Public Property HasBeenReadByID As Integer
  Public Property UserName As String
End Class
```

I have struggled a little with the need to use an 'Include' in my queries such as follows:

```
viewModel.ChannelItem = db.ChannelItems.Include("Anchor").Include("Comments").Where(Function(x) x.ChannelItemID = ChannelItemID).FirstOrDefault()
```

I say struggle because I thought there should be a way to configure my project so that Anchor and Comments load automatically, but I can't seem to figure that out.  That's not my question, but only a way of explaining why I'm so bound up in 'Include' statements.  It's the only way I am able to currently make sure all the data is retrieved during the query.  Now, on to my question.

Within my current project configuration, I now need to include the HasBeenReadBy data in the UserPost.  I would like that data retrieved when I get ChannelItems in a query, but I can't include HasBeenReadBy as follows:

```
Dim allAnchorsInType = db.ChannelItems.Include("Anchor").Include("Comments").Include("HasBeenReadBy").Where(Function(x) x.Anchor.Type = ChannelType).ToList()
```

because HasBeenReadBy is not part of ChannelItems.

So how do I "Include" HasBeenReadBy, or is that even possible?  While probably obvious, there is HasBeenReadBy data for the Anchor property, as well as HasBeenReadBy data in each of the Comments in the Comments property.

Or is my Class design just plain naive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C# we use something like following to select multilevel objects

```
db.ChannelItems
.Include(i => i.Anchor)                
.Include(i => i.Comments.Select(c => c.HasBeenReadBy))
```

Hope you could convert it to corresponding VB code.

Comment: Perfect!  Thx.  Conversion is:  **db.ChannelItems.Include(Function(i) i.Anchor).Include(Function(i) i.Comments.[Select](Function(c) c.HasBeenReadBy))**, per the wonderful page by Telerik at [http://converter.telerik.com/](http://converter.telerik.com/)

Comment: btw, forgot to mention the helpful hint to use a predicate function in place of the hard coded string I was using.  That way intellisense kicks in.  Can only give 1 +1 and already did.

Comment: btw, I also forgot to mention that I don't see anything wrong with your class design. Anyway, glad to help.